# Can i host multiple apps in one droplet in digitalocean

Tags: deployment, digital-ocean

I have two apps in Nuxtjs (client and admin platform), and i want to deploy them on Digital Ocean.

I think that it would be enough with the $5 droplet but i don't really know if it's possible to deploy both on the same droplet and point one to example.com and the other to admin.example.com.

Also, i would like to know if it's possible implement something like webmail there (i will not use the disk to save messages but to create the accounts and use them with pop3 on gmail or outlook).

Answer (score 2):

You can host multiple apps on a single Droplet, but you will need to run a reverse proxy such as `nginx` along with the apps to handle routing based on your domains. You can read about the installation of nginx [here](https://www.serverlab.ca/tutorials/linux/web-servers-linux/how-to-configure-multiple-domains-with-nginx-on-ubuntu/). Then the idea is to configure nginx to look something like this:

```
server {
  server_name example.com;
  location / {
     proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
  }
}

server {
  server_name admin.example.com;
  location / {
     proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
  }
}
```

Assuming your 2 Nuxtjs apps are running on localhost:3000 and localhost:5000 of the Droplet.

Comment: Thanks! do you know if it's possible create emails from droplet?

Comment: You should purchase smtp or mailing services seperately instead of running your smtp server on a droplet. Or you could purchase hosting and domain from a provider that offeres them alongside webmail and change you nameservers accordinly

Comment: You should purchase smtp or mailing services seperately instead of running your smtp server on a droplet. Or you could purchase hosting and domain from a provider that offeres them alongside webmail and change you nameservers accordinly